# encryption mechanism used by pgp_sym_encrypt function

Tags: postgresql

I am using pgp_sym_encrypt function to encrypt data in a postgresql column. What is the type of encryption being used by this function? Is there a way to change the encryption type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html):

> **F.26.3.8. Options for PGP Functions**
>
> Options are named to be similar to GnuPG. An option's value should be
>   given after an equal sign; separate options from each other with
>   commas. For example:
>
> ```
>   pgp_sym_encrypt(data, psw, 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256')
> ```
>
> All of the options except convert-crlf apply only to encrypt
>   functions. Decrypt functions get the parameters from the PGP data.
>
> The most interesting options are probably compress-algo and
>   unicode-mode. The rest should have reasonable defaults.
>
> *F.26.3.8.1. cipher-algo*
>
> Which cipher algorithm to use.
>
> Values: bf, aes128, aes192, aes256 (OpenSSL-only: 3des, cast5)
>
> Default: aes128
>
> Applies to: pgp_sym_encrypt, pgp_pub_encrypt
>
> *F.26.3.8.2. compress-algo*
>
> Which compression algorithm to use. Only available if PostgreSQL was
>   built with zlib.
>
> Values:   0 - no compression
>
> 1 - ZIP compression
>
> 2 - ZLIB compression (= ZIP plus meta-data and block CRCs)
>
> Default: 0
>
> Applies to: pgp_sym_encrypt, pgp_pub_encrypt

I believe it uses aes-128 by default, but this might depend on the version. It has been aes-128 since at least version 8.3.